# PHP_XLSXWriter_plus Missing Data For Large Mysql Data Sets

Tags: php, mysql, angularjs, excel

I am trying out this library, because PHPExcel is in capable of not using up 3GBs of ram (probably more) when trying to download 143,000+ mysql records. So far this library has been an improvement as I can generate an .xlsx file without exhausting the php memory limit.

However, I am running into a problem where it fills in most of the data, but a couple of columns have only 3\4 of the expected values and other columns is a hit or miss if it fills in the value for a particular cell.

For example, one column is called Submit Date and its format is datetime in the database, but a string from the php query. Out of 143,828 rows of data only the first 19,483 rows have the date values filled in.

I can confirm that the missing values in the submit date column and the other missing cells do have a value\data within the mysql database. Also, the submit date column is used in a ORDER BY clause in the mysql query in case that has anything to do with this problem.

So I am trying to figure out if this is a (common?) problem with this library when downloading a large data set? Or the problem more lies more on my code up until calling on this library to generate the .xslx file.

Thanks.

Comment: It seems like a problem with the data rather than the library. If the library works for the first thousands of rows, I don't see why it would stop working after that. To make sure the problem is coming from your data, you can try using another library like [Spout](https://github.com/box/spout) to see if you can reproduce the problem. If so, then your data is bad, otherwise that's a library problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to load not all rows at once...

sample: php + js

1. php http://pastebin.com/ZLsNXayd
2. js http://pastebin.com/QvPux6Hs

Comment: and cache writing
    $cacheMethod = PHPExcel_CachedObjectStorageFactory::cache_to_phpTemp;
    $cacheSettings = array( 'memoryCacheSize ' => '256MB');
    PHPExcel_Settings::setCacheStorageMethod($cacheMethod, $cacheSettings);

Comment: Thank you Alex. I ended up trying out Spout with success before your reply. However, I did make use of your suggestion by altering my php script to acquire 50,000 records at a time, write them to the stream, and free the memory for each mysql query results before outputting the file.  This allowed me to generate an xlsx file for 230,000+ records while keeping under 1GB of ram usage.